# Javascript regex to check only numbers and minus at the start of string

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

Hello I am trying to make a regex in this input field to accept only 4 numbers not greater than 2934, but accept a negative one too (-2394).

I want to allow the minus sign only at the start of the string, and then 4 numbers only, not greater than 2934 (positive and negative, because they are coordinates.

Already tried the given solutions here, but I am missing something.

```js
function numonly(myfield, e, dec){
      // max input value of 4196 x 4196
      $("#mlat,#mlon").keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/,"");
        if (val => 2934){
          !/^\s*$/.test(val);
          val = (parseInt(val) > 2934) ? 2934 : val;
        }
        else {
          (!/^\s*$/.test(val));
          val = (parseInt(val) > 2934) ? 2934 : val;
        }
        $(this).val(val);
      });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mlat" type="text" name="mlat" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return numonly(this,event)"><br>
<input type="text" name="mlon" id="mlon" maxlength="4"  onkeypress="return numonly(this,event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following method :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="mlat" type="text" name="mlat" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return numonly(this,event)"><br>
<input type="text" name="mlon" id="mlon" maxlength="5"  onkeypress="return numonly(this,event)">
<script type="text/javascript">

function numonly(myfield, e, dec){

  // max input value of 4196 x 4196
  $("#mlat").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val().replace(/-?\d+[^0-9]+/,"");
    if (val => 2934){
      !/^\s*$/.test(val);
      if (val > 0) {
        val = (parseInt(val) > 2934) ? 2934 : val;
      }else{
        val = (parseInt(val) > -2394) ? val : -2394;
      }

    }
    else {
      (!/^\s*$/.test(val));
      if (val > 0) {
        val = (parseInt(val) > 2934) ? 2934 : val;
      }else{
        val = (parseInt(val) > -2394) ? val : -2394;
      }
    }
    $(this).val(val);
  })
};


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and replace the maxlength to 5 to handle `-` sign in input tag.

Comment: This works great. Any idea how I can prevent the input to be something like -2---

Comment: edited the answer. now just copy the answer and run it in browser.

Comment: Nice! Almost perfect. If I put A minus at the start it changes the value to -2394, or if I try to erase the numbers when I erase the 4 numbers it changes back to -2394.

Comment: for that thing you can call the function on button click because now it triggers on keypress that's why you are getting the issue.

Comment: @RogerHN have you got your answer?

Comment: yeah, sorry, forgot to check it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to make a regex in this input field to accept only 4
>   numbers not greater than 2934, but accept a negative one too (-2394).

No need for regex here, use

```
var minValue = -2394;
var maxValue = 2934;    
var val = +$(this).val().replace(/[^0-9-]+/g,""); //using your own regex to replace non-numeric characters
var isValid = !isNaN( val ) && val < maxValue && val > minValue ;
```

Also, i noticed that you want to make these values as upper and lower bound

```
if ( !isNaN( val ) )
{
    var finalVal  = isValid ? val : (val < 0 ? minValue  : maxValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with that regex it doesn't allow me to input negative sign in front of the numbers.

Comment: @RogerHN Sure, updated the regex... added a global modifier as well.

Comment: I am having a problem that if I start typing and then try to erase a char it keeps the number zero and doesn't allow me to place minus at the start. Is this normal? https://jsfiddle.net/2t4hdc1b/6/  Also if I type minus it shows the maxValue instead.

Comment: What I am missing?

Comment: I have put an if condition to which only changes the value, if the original value was a valid integer to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
function numonly(myfield, e, dec){
  // max input value of 4196 x 4196
  $("#mlat,#mlon").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9-]+/,"");
    if (parseInt(val) > 2934){
      val = (parseInt(val) > 2934) ? 2934 : val;
    }
    else {
      val = (parseInt(val) < -2934) ? -2934 : val;
    }
    $(this).val(val);
  });
}
```

Increase your max length to 5 to cater the '-'

```
<input id="mlat" type="text" name="mlat" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return numonly(this,event)"><br>
<input type="text" name="mlon" id="mlon" maxlength="5"  onkeypress="return numonly(this,event)">
```